# Flask + Restplus adding route('/')

Tags: python, flask

I'm getting an 404 errors when trying to setup routes for a Flask + Restplus app.

```
@api.route('/')
class asd(Resource):
  def get(self):
    return "asd"
```

Always return 404 error/ If I add @api.route('/'something) I can access "/something" URL without an error.

What do I miss? Or it's not possible when using Flask + Restplus?

I've tried adding '/' route tu the api an dto the app with same results.

app and api defines in separate class for server

```
class Server(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = Flask(__name__)
        self.api = Api(self.app, 
            version='0.1', 
            title='API',
            description='A simple API', 
            doc = environment_config["swagger-url"]
        )

def run(self):
       self.app.run(
            debug = environment_config["debug"], 
            port = environment_config["port"]
        )

server = Server()
```